# How to save web contents to another html file

Tags: javascript, electron, web-content

I'm new to JavaScript and Electron Projects. I have a small task to Run a Webpage in which I have "download" button, if I hit the button I have to get all contents and sources code to be downloaded for the current page. Here my Sample work :

**browser.js**

```
onload = function() {
var webview = document.querySelector('webview');
doLayout();

document.querySelector('#back').onclick = function() {
webview.goBack();
};

document.querySelector('#download').onclick = function() {

var urlStr = webview.getURL()

alert(urlStr)

// alert(webview.getWebContents());
  };
}
```

Currently I am able to get Url in Alert View, but I'm not able to get webpage contents

Note: Please give solution only in JavaScript not in jQuery

Comment: can anyone please do Reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally this simple code helped me to download the html file

```
var htmlContent = [""];
var bl = new Blob(htmlContent, {type: "text/html"});
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = urlStr;
a.download = "new.html";
a.hidden = true;
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.innerHTML = "something random - nobody will see this, it doesn't matter  what you put here";
a.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this without having some server-side code that reads the file required and sends it with download-headers.

Since Electron is a CSS/HTML/JS framework that also focusses on app development I doubt if this is possible within Electron. Given it's Node it might be possible (since Node is server-side), but I'm lacking in knowledge/experience in Electron on if this is possible.

You might want to check out this page in their documentation though: http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/download-item/

Comment: bro can u give simple solution how to download current wepage to new html page

Comment: Sorry bro I cannot. Like I said, I'm lacking in knowledge/experience on how to do this in Electron/Node. The answer I gave was purely theoretical. Have you already read the documentation?

Comment: since i completely new to this language i dono how to implement it

Comment: normally in JavaScript is it possible to write currnt webpage into .html file and download them